# permalinks - renaming of permalinks

Tags: permalinks

u have standard permalinks on my blog. But, i'm about to change to a full blown website and would like to amend the individual pages so, I can continue to pick up the google rankings.

My website is www.fishface.co

The 2 pages I want to re-name are

http://www.fishface.co/?page_id=264

&

http://www.fishface.co/?page_id=615

i am hoping to rename the pages www.fishface.co/stonhambarnscarboot

& www.fishface.co/stonhambarnscarbootblog

I'm not a qualified web percival so, I need an idiot guide.

At the moment it's looking like setting up the new pages and maybe getting them to also search for the old links.

Or aiming the old links at the new links.

Re-naming would be better but on Wordpress it looks like if I rename in the settings it will change every page to variationms of the same thing.

can someone come up with a simple solution or suggestions. Either way I need to set up the new site and don't want to lose the people that use my blog on wordpress.

Comment: You can redirect your old url's by adding some lines in `htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and create rule like this :

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^fishface.co/stonhambarnscarboot$    page264.php    [NC,L]    # Handle
RewriteRule    ^fishface.co/stonhambarnscarbootblog$    page615.php    [NC,L]    # Handle
```

Here is a good guide easy to follow : [URL Rewriting for beginners](https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/)

Comment: Perhaps a civil answer this time.By enabling mod rewrite what exactly will it do and will it not lose google points (so to speak). At the moment I have Wordpress using the two pages. When i activate the new website i'm hoping to get it to pick up the old web addresses (page 264 and page 615) because they are high on google.

Comment: is mod rewrite better than htaccess. What is the best option please.

Comment: Also, I need to have the new site running first and can I then pick up the old pages. Any thoughts appreciated